# How can I configure SNI on Service Fabric

Tags: azure, sni, azure-service-fabric

Im am attempting to host a web api in service fabric which needs to respond to web requests from other parties.  In the documentation for one of the third parties they specifically call out that they do not support SNI in the web hooks.  It appears like our web api hosted on service fabric has SNI turned on.

Is there a way to override the default httpsys behavior for service fabric nodes so that I can turn off SNI (or at least supply a default wildcard certificate for non SNI enabled clients)?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the ipport=0.0.0.0:443 using netsh to use your certificate will setup the fallback certificate.
The netsh call would look like this:

> netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443 certhash=[YourCertificateThumbprint] appid={c026c540-804e-4039-9089-9a11caeb5e7d} certstorename=MY

The guid for appid is just a random guid (is used so you can see which tool was responsible for the configuration, for example IIS has a specific Guid).
To see what is configured you can run:

> netsh http show sslcert

Now you could place this in a setup.cmd/bat and configure this to run in the SetupEntryPoint of your service manifest. Be sure to configure the setup entry point to run under the "LocalSystem" account.

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-runas-security) for instructions how to configure the SetupEntryPoint.